# Transforming simplest protocol into a Sigma-protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-design, sigma-protocol

I have some questions from previous years exams, I hope you could help me with them. :)

> Suppose that a protocol satisfies the properties of a $\Sigma$-protocol, except that it is only (plain) honest-verifier zero-knowledge. Show how to transform this protocol into a $\Sigma$-protocol for the same relation by assuming that the verifier generates $c \in C$ at random (with uniform distribution), where $(C,+)$ is an additive finite group.

Comment: Are you using "an additive finite group" for "a group whose binary operation is $\hspace{1.7 in}$ written $\textbf{+}$" or "a quotient group of $\langle \mathbb{Z},+\rangle$"? $\;\;$

Comment: I think it is "a group whose binary operation is written +".

Comment: What is your (or your lecturer's) definition of a Sigma-protocol? I'm presuming (s)he is including full ZK among the properties since the question mentions "only HVZK", is that what you're after?

Comment: The question used to be an exercise in these [Lecture Notes Cryptographic Protocols](https://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/CryptographicProtocols/LectureNotes.pdf). It is now included as Proposition 5.2 with a full proof. (A bit long to copy and paste as part of this answer.)